# JS: Arrow Function - return 'false' instead of 'true'

Tags: javascript

I have been through similar topics here and went through documentation, but still have a problem with the following block of code:

```js
var distanceToPump = 50;
var mpg = 25;
var fuelLeft = 2;

var zeroFuel = (distanceToPump, mpg, fuelLeft) => { return ( mpg * fuelLeft ) 
== distanceToPump ? true : false; }
console.log(zeroFuel())
```

The function returns false, while the ternary operator returns true. Where is the mistake? UPD. My question is where does this difference comes from, where is the mistake in the function zeroFuel?

Comment: Why do you even need a ternary here?

Comment: `(distanceToPump, mpg, fuelLeft) => mpg * fuelLeft == distanceToPump`

Comment: You are not calling the function, so unclear what you mean.

Comment: Just for the sake of practice, I am a newbie.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/doyanohita/1/edit?js,console — can't reproduce the problem

Comment: Sorry guys. I edited the question.

Comment: @Quentin I added the snippet which returns `false`

Comment: `(undefined * undefined) == undefined`

Answer (score 1):

When you call `zeroFuel` you aren't passing any arguments.

The local variables defined as the parameters, therefore, get the value `undefined`.

`(undefined * undefined) == undefined` is false.

The variables with the same names in the wider scope are never used.

Comment: @Quentin was the snippet that bad?

Answer (score -1):

Just tested in console and `zeroFuel(distanceToPump, mpg, fuelLeft)` returns true.

Comment: Quentin has pointed to my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for helping others, in the future please provide a more clear explanation when answering the question, such as why true was returned, how to avoid (if any) the same mistake, etc.